# UICollectionView not scrolling horizontally even though I can get it to scroll vertically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to get a collectionview to scroll horizontally,

If I change the scrolldirection to .vertical it scrolls just fine but I can't figure out why I am not able to make this work horizontally. If I shrink the cell size down I can see multiple cells created but I am still not able to get it to move at all. The cell or item is responsive when I try to scroll the horizontalscrollindicator is visible. Any ideas?

This is my code that I am using to set up the layout:

````
                let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
                layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
                layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 12
                layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

                let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
                cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                cv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                cv.backgroundColor = .green

                cv.clipsToBounds = false
                cv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                cv.register(detailViewCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "detailViewCollectionCell")
                return cv
            }()```
````

Comment: show your whole `UICollectionView` code.